# Who is "he" in news reporter words?

Tags: meaning

In Drama film/Biography film *The People vs. Larry Flynt (1996)*, Larry Flynt, Hustler Magazine, filed a case on Preacher,Jerry Falwell 
in supreme court on charges of copyright violation of his magazine, 
So News reporter told this news:

> God versus the devil. America's minister versus America's pimp. Today
>   is the showdown. Many were surprised by the high court's decision  to
>   hear Flynt's case, but **he** had some unlikely supporters filing  briefs
>   on his behalf: The New York Times, the American Newspaper Publishers
>   Association, and the Association of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *he* in that sentence refers to Larry Flynt.

> Many were surprised by the high court's decision to hear **Flynt's** case, but **he** had some unlikely supporters filing briefs on his behalf: The New York Times, the American Newspaper Publishers Association, and the Association of...

means that people were surprised by the decision to hear Flynt's case but that decision was most likely because Flynt had unlikely supporters filing briefs on his behalf.